# web Api en ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

estoy creando servicios en ASP.NET Framework conectándolo con SQL Server , solo tengo una tabla y quiero listas los datos que están en la ahí pero no me carga nada y me sale este mensaje , estoy utilizando Postman para mostrar los resultados , ¿Qué significa ese mensaje? , también quiero crear los servicios de buscar por id, crear , eliminar y actualizar . Gracias de antemano

**Este es el mensaje que me muestra en el postman al listar**

```
"Message": "Error.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "El tipo 'ObjectContent`1' no pudo serializar el cuerpo de respuesta para el tipo de contenido 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": null,
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "Error.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The connection string 'DBConexion' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.\"",
        "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
        "StackTrace": "   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   en Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   en Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   en Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   en Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   en System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   en System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   en System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   en System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---\r\n   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()"
    }
}
```

**este es mi conexion**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prueba.Models
{
    public partial class DBConexion:DbContext
    {
        public DBConexion()
            : base("name=DBConexion")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**esta es mi case Employee**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prueba.Models
{
    [Table("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**este es mi controlador**

```
using Prueba.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HttpGetAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute;
using HttpPostAttribute = System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute;
using RouteAttribute = System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute;

namespace Prueba.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        public DBConexion db = new DBConexion();

        // GET: Employee
        
        public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
          return db.Employees;
        }

        [Route("api/crear")]
        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic crear()
        {
            return "hola";
        }
    }
}
```

**este es mi connectionString**

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBConexion" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-DS55F02\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CRUDDB;user id=sa;passwork=aldair19 Integrated Security=true"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: El error dice que no configuraste correctamente el conection string.. mostra tu archivo config

Comment: @gbianchi ya agregué mi connectionString

Comment: en tu cadena de conexión dice passwork y se escribe password. Al finalizar el password, coloca punto y coma (;), luego de aldair19;

Answer (score 0):

Tú conexión esta mal te dejo un ejemplo

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Y en el config agregar tu conexión

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(servidor);Initial Catalog=(nombre de bd);Integrated Security=True; user=(usuario); password=(contraseña); MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```